# Handling SQL reserved table and column names

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

Is there a way to handle reserved table & column names in your app which can work through all kinds of databases like Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, PostGreSQL etc.

Currently, I have to do the following :

Oracle - use double quotes.
MySQL - Use backtick or double quotes (depends if ANSI_QUOTES mode is enabled)
SQL Server  - Use brackets
PostGreSQL - use double quotes.

I am aware that ANSI standard states to use double quotes but unfortunately not all dbms seem to support them.

Comment: Unfortunately not. You could write a small script that parses the SQL and replaces the quoting characters with the needed ones but there is no consistency across RDBMS on this.

Comment: Thanks. But, there is an API in DataBaseMetaData.getIdentifierQuoteString() which tends to give the appropriate quoting. I tried this on MySQL and returns a backtick. Can this API be relied upon for other DB vendors ? (Any suggestions0

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server support double quotes as well?

Comment: So I have tested it, and SQL Server uses double quotes just like ANSI specifies. Is your problem solved then?

Comment: It seem we have to set SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON to enable double quotes in SQL server. But, I believe that should be OK to have config requirement. So, I can go ahead and use double quotes throughout. Thanks a lot everyone..

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use double quotes. That's what the standard says, and surprisingly, it actually works on most platforms.

Require that MySQL have `ANSI_QUOTES` enabled, or [set it at the session level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html):

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI'
```

(I used `ANSI` not just `ANSI_QUOTES` here because it makes MySQL generally a bit saner).

PostgreSQL doesn't require any special settings for identifiers (though very old versions need `standard_conforming_strings = on` to handle literals sensibly).

Neither does Oracle.

Modern MS-SQL [shouldn't require any special settings to support double quoted identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx):

> When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON (default), all strings delimited by double quotation marks are interpreted as object identifiers

The docs suggest that was the case in MS-SQL 2008, and if you still care about 2005 in a new application you have bigger problems.

SQLFiddles:

- [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bccaa)
- [MS-SQL 2008](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec79a)
- [Oracle 11g R2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ec79a)

Interestingly, I found that the SQLFiddle for PostgreSQL failed with an odd error. I suspect an SQLFiddle bug, as it's fine on the PostgreSQL command line and via PgJDBC. It fails with `there is no table that match the following pattern [with]`.

All that said, if you're seriously trying to write ANSI SQL, I hope you don't plan on using:

- Date/time maths
- String concatenation
- Non-trivial aggregates
- Window functions (MySQL still doesn't support them)
- Common table expressions
- SQL/XML
- Arbitrary precision decimal data types
- Any kind of user defined procedure or function
- Any kind of user-defined type
- ... lots more

because different vendors use different names, have different support for features, etc.

(On a side note, if I ever meet the person who decided to call Microsoft SQL Server "SQL" in a dark alley...)

Comment: Yes.. But, even SQL Server needs a similar setting to be enabled.

Comment: @MuraM Not on vaguely recent versions.

Comment: Do we know, starting which version of SQL Server is double quotes supported be default?

Comment: @MuraM Per the linked documentation, at least 2008, if not older. And as I said, if you still care about 2005 you've got big problems.

Comment: I may be wrong but as per the linked documentation, it says "Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 through current version)", which should mean that a special setting (SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER { ON | OFF }) should be enabled, right?

Comment: @MuraM **When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON (default) ...**

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it on a SQL Server 2008 and the metadata API call returns double quotes. So, I am good.